# Matplotlib 2.0.0: axes set_position ignored if using tight_layout

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Python 3.4 and Matplotlib 2.0.0 on a Mac. The problem that troubles me is the ax.set_position() functions seems to be ignored if using tight_layout(). 
A similar effect is observed when putting subplots_adjust() after set_position (see the code comment).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random as random

data = random.randn(255,255)

plt.close()

fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,1)

ax=axes[0]

im=ax.imshow(data, aspect='auto')
cb=plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('X data')
ax.set_ylabel('Y data')

pos0 = ax.get_position()

ax=axes[1]
pos1 = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([pos1.x0, pos1.y0, pos0.width, pos1.height])

ax.plot([0,1])
ax.set_xlabel('Big')
ax.set_ylabel('Small')

plt.tight_layout() # put  plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2) here produces similar results

plt.show()
```

This produces [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHPDB.png). What I expect is something like this [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLYPO.png).

I think this is a bug, and reported to matplotlib on github. But so far no reply or whatever. So am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: It's definitely not a bug. I think you misunderstood `tight_layout` and `subplots_adjust`. They both adjust the layout of the subplots automatically. It does make little to no sense at all to first manually position the axes and then let them be repositioned automatically.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense for tight_layout. But I find it a little strange for subplot_adjusts.

Comment: Both commands do not differ in that they automatically adjust the axes positions.